# Difference between Excel .csv and plain .csv?

Tags: excel, csv, file-type

I am running Windows 7 and have MS Office installed. Any time I download a .csv file the "file type" line in the "save as..." dialog defaults to "Microsoft Office Excel comma separated values file". **Is there actually a Microsoft specific format that is distinct from "plain" .csv?**

Googling the relevant terms returns various incredibly uninformative pages such as [this one](http://extension.informer.com/csv/). Is any information lost or gained, or anything encoded differently by using this format than by just treating a file as a .csv, conforming to the [general standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2)?

Comment: Unfortunately, [there is no "plain .csv"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard), so your question is based on a non-sequitur.

Comment: @hyde I meant "conforming to the conventions in RFC4180", as implied by my second paragraph. The question is whether any information is gained by knowing that a file is of the Excel .csv type or not.

Comment: some time after RFC4180 was published Excel has been made compatible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are almost certainly differences.
From the top of my head: English Excel uses "," as a seperator. German locale uses ";" as a seperator, requiring an additional importing step if you want to import a csv with a comma seperator. This is not unique to german locales, roughly 1/4 to 1/3 of the world uses ";".

Also, there might be differences in how complicated strings are escaped (; and " in texts) which are probably different from program to program.
This is not excels fault, since the csv "format" is not really standardised and there are uncountable numbers of programs which are rolling their own csv parser, which leads to all sorts of problems because they forgot to handle corner cases.

I once read the comment that csv is the plague of data exchange formats because it is so difficult to do right. I could not agree more, I have to deal with them on a daily basis and they are extremly annoying to work with. 
Open source fans will hate me for this, but I think csv is a poor choice for data exchange, even xlsx is better because it has rules which are well defined.

Comment: Isn't the ";" vs. "," for separator a question of a parameter set within whatever program I am using and not a difference between programs? Or are you saying that Excel's default to "," is locality agnostic?

Comment: @WAF It depends :( In excel, there is no way to change the seperator unless you are changing the locale of the system. Other programs might default to whatever they choose, maybe giving you an option. Keep in mind that csv can stand for "comma seperated file" or "character seperated file".

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that before. I've always preferred whitespace separation anyway. I just happen to have an application that requires parsing CSVs at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things going on. The abbreviation (and suffix) "CSV" can mean character-separated values or it can mean comma-separated values. "Microsoft Office Excel comma separated values file" is a disambiguation, and means that you have a number of values in a record, with the field values separated by a comma.

The values themselves, in comma-separated value files, may contain commas if they are properly stropped (quoted). Usually, the stropping is putting a double quote around some or all of the field.

MS Excel also supports newlines in the middle of fields, again being properly stropped.

Comment: As per BobD CSV (Character separated values / Comma separated values). Excel uses Region and Language >> Customize Format >> "List Separator"  character as separator. It defaults to comma but can be changed to any character.

Comment: Excel seems to conform to RFC4180 in all ways, at-least for ASCII data, I seem to recall the being some problems with UTF-8 but they can be "fixed" by corrupting your CSV with a "BOM" at the start.

Answer (score -1):

What I have seen from the behavior of Excel when opening "Microsoft Excel CSV files" and plain ".csv" is that the former is openened in Excel directly and the latter requires import through the database ribbon. Why is this behavior different on files for which I cannot find structural dissimilarities is what calls my attention.

Comment: I recommend to rephrase a little in order to reduce the (very slight) impression of asking a question instead of giving an answre. To be clear, that impression probably hits only somewhat hasty reades with a  more doggish mindset. But it could be what got you the unappreciative feedback. Ideally try for [answer].